System.Text.Json : handle multiple different JSON responses by the same class during deserialization
I am integrating some API and getting variant response for error field
{ "errors" : "amar" } 
{ "errors" : "akbar" }
{ "error" : "anthony" }

My error handling class has one property string Error.
How can I deserialize in an efficient way in that without try catch? I am using .NET Core 8.0
For array of strings, I can have comma-separated errors.
My model for class looks like this at the moment:
public record ApiResponseError([property: JsonPropertyName("error")] string Errors)

Note
Also I have automapper mapping with same Model which i don't want to break either
public record ApiResponseErrorResponseModel(string Errors)


I think you need to use custom converter using "JsonConverter".  I've not done this in system.text.json (only Newtonsoft) so can't really help your further, but you can take a look at this for more information:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0

Do you mean you want to bind errors,error or other name to the string Error inside api model binding?

According to your description, you could create a custom json converter to handle the json for the APIERROR record.
You could create the converter like below:
public class ApiResponseErrorConverter : JsonConverter<ApiResponseError>
{
    public override ApiResponseError Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string errorMessage = null;

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();

                if (propertyName == "error" || propertyName == "errors")
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
                    {
                        errorMessage = reader.GetString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new JsonException();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (errorMessage == null)
        {
            throw new JsonException("The JSON does not contain an 'error' or 'errors' property.");
        }

        return new ApiResponseError(errorMessage);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ApiResponseError value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WriteString("error", value.Error);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

Register it inside the program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new ApiResponseErrorConverter());
});

Test with the controller
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(ApiResponseError error)
    {
        return Ok(new { Error = error });
    }
}

Result:

and


In .Net 8 some new attributes came into play, which help to solve this without writing your own converter:
public class MyErrorClass
{
    public List<string> Errors { get; init; } = [];

    [JsonObjectCreationHandling(JsonObjectCreationHandling.Populate)]
    [JsonPropertyName("errors")]
    [JsonInclude]
    private ICollection<string> _multipleErrors { get { return Errors; } }

    [JsonPropertyName("error")]
    [JsonInclude]
    private string _singleError { set { Errors.Add(value); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Errors: {string.Join(", ", Errors)}";
    }
}

You can test the different JSONs with this little program:
public static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var error = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyErrorClass>("""{"error":"Some single error"}""");
        Console.WriteLine(error);

        error = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyErrorClass>("""{"errors": ["Some array single error"]}""");
        Console.WriteLine(error);

        error = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyErrorClass>("""{"errors": ["Some array error", "Another array error"]}""");
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}

This would make the desired usage of the property better, but unfortunately this doesn't work:
[JsonObjectCreationHandling(JsonObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]
[JsonPropertyName("errors")]
[JsonInclude]
private ICollection<string> _multipleErrors { set { Errors.AddRange(value); } }


needed to try similar implementation in record type

I have similar response record model which I am using Automapper for mapping. don't want to break that either

You could create a custom converter. Would be something like this
public class ApiResponseErrorJsonConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var converter = new ApiResponseErrorJsonConverterInner();

        return converter;
    }

    private class ApiResponseErrorJsonConverterInner : JsonConverter<ApiResponseError>
    {
        public override ApiResponseError? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            {
                throw new JsonException();
            }

            string? error = null;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                {
                    throw new JsonException();
                }

                var prop = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();

                switch (prop)
                {
                    case "error":
                        error = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case "errors":
                        error = reader.GetString(); // Not sure if multiple errors are comma separated from API already?
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return new(error ?? string.Empty);
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ApiResponseError value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WriteString("error", value.Error);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}

Finally decorate your response class with the JsonConverterAttribute
[JsonConverter(typeof(ApiResponseErrorJsonConverter))]
public record ApiResponseError(string Error);

